# Detect client windows OS version and EDITION?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, user-agent

I am working on an public facing ASP.net MVC site which requires me to identify the OS of the client machine. More importantly to detect if the client has **Windows 10 S** installed. The navigator object in JS does give the OS version as 10.0 from the user agent for win 10 but i wanted to know if there is a way using client side scripting to find the edition of Windows to find if the client OS is **Windows 10 S**. Or if there is any other way using the request object in the server side will also work.

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks !

Comment: There is no reliable way to do so. You may have found or constructed a way that seems semi-reliable so far, but any 'system information' a server gets from a client through the browser can be spoofed, faked and tweaked, or it can simply be incomplete.

Comment: thanks for your response. I agree the information can be spoofed but wanted to check if there is any work around to target that specific OS edition. Anyway thanks again for your valuable input.